# Flutter Inspector says "no running applications" even though I'm running my app on my emulator

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

My Flutter Inspector isn't showing anything up. I've tried to run my app on several devices, including a physical one, a Pixel 3 emulator running Q, Pixel 3 running Pie, and Chrome as a web app. [Flutter Inspector on the sidebar still says "No running applications."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FHUr.png) Anyone know a fix?